# how we can give value using keyboard in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

In Oracle you can `SELECT` data from a table and request interactive user input to be used in the `WHERE` condition. This is done by specifying `&column` in the WHERE statement and user input will be prompted and used in its place. For example:

```
SELECT Ename, Deptno, Job, Sal FROM Emp 
WHERE Sal &GiveNegationState BETWEEN 1100 AND 2850 
SQL> / 

Enter value for givenegationstate: NOT


ENAME DEPTNO JOB SAL 

---------- ---------- --------- ---------- 

KING 10 PRESIDENT 5000 

JONES 20 MANAGER 2975 

JAMES 30 CLERK 950 

FORD 20 ANALYST 3000 

SMITH 20 CLERK 800 

SCOTT 20 ANALYST 3000
```

Can this be done in MySQL?

Comment: This is a function of the tool used to access the database, not of the database itself.  What tool are you using?

Comment: Are you asking about replicating SQL*Plus substitution variables in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL Query Browser @GordonLinoff

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such option present in MySQL.